# Is there a way in Java to incrementally change a class name?

Tags: java, migration, classname

I have a large body of Java code that uses a class XXX.  Over time, the meaning of the class has changed, and the name is no longer appropriate.  To make the code more readable, I would like to change the name of the class to YYY.

One option is to edit all the files in a single pass and change XXX to YYY, but the actual name of the class is not unique -- there are other classes with the same name, different package -- so I need to look at code.  I would like to be able to make some changes, test that it is correct, and change some more, test some more, etc.  During this transition time, I want to be able to use YYY and XXX interchangeably.  Eventually I would eliminate the XXX.

What I need is an "alias" concept, where I could make YYY and alias of XXX, but Java does not have this.

I could make YYY a subclass of XXX with all the same constructors and methods.  That will work fine where a variable is declared XXX, and I assign a value of type YYY.   It will also work where a method parameter is XXX, and I pass a YYY.   But it will not work the other way around when the parameter is declared YYY and I have an XXX value to send.

I could inject YYY into the inheritance, so that XXX extends YYY, but I have the same problem as above: in code that has mixed use of XXX declarations and YYY values there is trouble.

The transition time will take a couple of months.  During this time, I don't care about performance or efficiency, I just need it to compile and run correctly enough to test.  **Any suggestions for a best practice to allow for incremental change of a class name in a body of Java code?**

**UPDATE**

The answer below is that while there is no way to do this in Java, there also should be no reason to either.  I followed up by installing and refactoring the code, and wrote up the experience in this blog post: [Don’t Suffer Poor Names](http://agiletribe.wordpress.com/2013/02/12/dont-suffer-poor-names/)

Comment: How big is your system?

Comment: The codebase is not `huge` as systems go, but on the large side for a single person to maintain:  100K to 200K lines.

Comment: Possible options: Give it a public version String field? Give it a private long serialVersionUID field?

Comment: Using IDE to rename is already in answers, but sounds like you *really* should look into modern SW development tools. Try at least Eclipse and Netbeans and IntelliJ Idea a with your codebase and see which feels best for you. Then fix the issues IDE complains about (configure to disable warnings you don't want to care about, after googling the ones you do not understand). Then see all the refactoring tools they offer, and stop gathering technical debt with code you know should be refactored, but it seems too hard.

Comment: +1 for wanting to change class name to reflect its behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an IDE such as [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org) and use its refactoring tools to rename the class. This will automatically change it everywhere it's used, update imports, etc.

Comment: do you have more details on specifically changing class names?

Comment: The real answer is "there is no way to have two equivalent class names"  I will look into using Eclipse to perform the change.